Umrah - Ihram Staying in relative house
Assalam alaikum, I'm planning for Umrah shortly with my family and I wanted to clarify two doubts. We are travelling to Jeddah from India, we have our relatives in Jeddah where we will be staying. Q1. I heard from my relative that we need to stay in Jeddah for 3 days before we perform Umrah? Is that true? Q2. If the answer for Q1 is yes, then can we stay in our relative house for 3 days then can I wear Ihram and perform Umrah. Kindly help me with these questions.
